# neo4j append unique to collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What's the best way to append an element to a collection, and to ensure that element appears only once in the collection?

Basically I have a list of tags and want to append new tags. Something like the query below, except all the element in n.index has to be unique

```
MATCH n, tag:Tag 
WHERE n.id='22cfb053-f772-4a3a-83c4-bb733e3dac0a' AND tag.name='hello world' 
SET n.index=n.index+tag.index 
RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider connecting your content nodes to the `Tag` nodes via a `TAGGED` relationship.

For combining collections use literal collections and +. `n.index` already has to be an array property.

```
MATCH (n:Content), (tag:Tag)
WHERE n.id='22cfb053-f772-4a3a-83c4-bb733e3dac0a' AND tag.name='hello world' 
SET n.index=n.index+[tag.index]
RETURN n;
```

Comment: The nodes are already connected to tag via such a relationship. The property is only for querying, because to support multiword tags, I had to add a search index to the content node and not just the tag. I thought it would be a good idea to remove duplicates from the index, but actually now that I've tried it a bit I think it might not be necessary after all. I guess if I need to do anything more specific for indexing, I have to use the Java API, right?

Comment: If you are using manual indexes that let you index whatever you want, then the Java API is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH n, tag:Tag
WHERE n.id='22cfb053-f772-4a3a-83c4-bb733e3dac0a' AND tag.name='hello world' 
WITH n, FILTER(x IN n.index WHERE x <> tag.index) as filtered
SET n.index=filtered + tag.index
RETURN n;
```